# MySQL workbench gives an error during exporting

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to export from my live server pc the databses for my web apps and site,but I get the following errors:

> 14:18:07 Dumping ct (all tables)
> Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\tmphnpsqu.cnf"  --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --routines --skip-triggers "ct"
> Error executing task: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
> Error executing task [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\tmphnpsqu.cnf'
> 14:18:08 Export of C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\dumps\Dump20210825 (2).sql has finished

Answer (score 0):

Open the task manager (ctrl+alt+delete) then go to processes, look for the process that's using the file and end it. After this, try exporting your schema again.

Comment: okay I will do it now,what can you say about the Error executing task: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128) ??

Comment: I think you're using the character 'ä' somewhere. A complex solution is to use a python script to decode and enceode the character. More simply you could just convert ä to a until you get a grip on the requisites to the writing a script (should you decide to).

Comment: Do you have leads as how I make such a python script?